# Builder Pattern in Typescript Similar to Java - chaining in parent class

Tags: typescript, builder

I am trying to implement TicTacToe game in typescript. In this, the class `HumanPlayer` and `BotPlayer` inherit ab `abstract class Player`.

To create the instance of HumanPlayer and BotPlayer - using `Builder pattern`.

```
enum TicTacToeSymbol {
    O="O", X="X"
};

abstract class Player {
  public symbol!: TicTacToeSymbol;
  abstract makeMove(): void;

  public getSymbol(): TicTacToeSymbol {
      return this.symbol;
  }

  public setSymbol(symbol: TicTacToeSymbol) {
      this.symbol = symbol;
      return this;
  }
}
```

In the above `Player` class, to reduce the code duplication, i've kept the common attribute `symbol` and its getter and setter.

```
class HumanPlayer extends Player {
    name!: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    makeMove(): void {
        console.log('make a move');
    }

    public static builder() {
        return new HumanPlayer.Builder();
    }

    static Builder = class Builder extends HumanPlayer {
        public setName(name: string) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public build() {
            const game = new HumanPlayer();

            game.name = this.name;

            return game;
        }
    }
}
```

But when i try to use it like this -

```
const humanPlayer = HumanPlayer.builder().setName("XYZ").setSymbol(TicTacToeSymbol.X).build();

console.log(humanPlayer); // HumanPlayer: {"name": "XYZ" }
```

But its not setting the symbol. One solution i have in mind is to move the setter and getter in the child class i.e Human and Bot player, but that will have code duplication.

Is there any other way we can achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand why this would be done with a builder as opposed to a regular constructor. Are `name` and `symbol` expected to be readonly and immutable?  Currently they are neither.

Comment: there are multiple attibutes of humanPlayer object e.g email, photo and other etc that why used the builder pattern.

Comment: But you would just do this in the constructor with an object literal argument with multiple properties, instead of multiple static setters,.  I mean, if you really want to do a builder pattern you can, maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w21p1W).  This builder requires that you call all the setters exactly once before calling build.  But it's complicated to set up in a way that behaves generically.  Not sure if that meets your needs, since I don't quite understand your needs from this question.

Comment: (see prev comment) Again, I would use a constructor that takes a single object argument for this purpose, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzBGeW).  Unless you actually care about the intermediate stages of a partially built object, there's no reason to require people to call chained methods like this.  Something like `new MyClass({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3})` is much more conventional and easy to understand than `MyClass.Builder.setA(1).setB(2).setC(3).build()`. Java doesn't have object literals, so the former approach isn't available there.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for looking it, yes, with constructor this can be easily solved. I am learning design patterns and trying to build it in ts. 

My issue is - the `this` returned in the `setSymbol` function in abstract class is not of type Human/Bot player builder so i am not able to use the chaining. 

If I define a generic builder type, then this is working fine but not sure if its correct way to do it.

```interface BuilderT {
    setName(arg0: string): BuilderT;
    setSymbol(arg: string): BuilderT;
    build(): Player;
    new (): BuilderT;
}```

https://shorturl.at/MU034